# Using RegEx in VB.Net to get song information from filename

Tags: regex, vb.net

So I need a Regex ninja to help me on  this one since I know little to nothing about Regex. I would like to be able to retrieve information about a song from the filename based on a mask. Here is an example:

```
G:\Music\G\Green Day\(2001) International Superhits!\02. Green Day - Poprocks & Coke.mp3
```

So the mask would be:

```
$artist$\$album$\$track$. $artist$ - $title$.mp3
```

Seems like Regex would be perfect for this since it is solely dealing with strings. Anybody have a solution?

Thanks,
Randy

P.S. I know how to do it through code...looking to get it done with Regex.

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for output where $artist$ = G, $album$ = Green Day(2001) International Superhits!, $track$ = 02, and $title$ = Green Day - Poprocks & Coke. Is that correct?

Comment: I guess it would look at the string from right to left so: $title$ = Poprocks & Coke, $artist$ = Green Day, $track$ = 02, $album$ = (2001) International Superhits!      There should be another forward slash in my original string that separates the artist from the album...like this:G:\Music\G\Green Day\\(2001) International Superhits!\02. Green Day - Poprocks & Coke.mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with regular expressions. If you write the mask yourself, you should simply write it as a regex right away. If not, you'll have to transform it into one, but that shouldn't be too difficult, once you see what the pattern looks like.

The main question is, what could those variables contain. For simplicity, for each of them I'll assume that they can contain any character except backslashes. Such a character is matched by `[^\\]`. This is a negated character class, which matches everything except the characters contained inside (and the first backslash is to escape the second one). You can repeat this with `+` (requiring at least one character). For the track I'll make an exception and allow only digits.

So that would make your pattern something like

```
[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\\d+[.]\s*[^\\]+\s*-\s*[^\\]+[.]mp3$
```

The `$` is to anchor the pattern to the end of the string.

Note that I put the periods in character classes. Otherwise they would match any character except line breaks - you could as well just escape the period, but I prefer the character class for readability. For the spaces, I used `\s*`, which matches an arbitrary amount (and kind) of whitespace, including no whitespace at all.

The question is now how to get this into your variables. You can *capture* parts of your match, by surrounding the desired part in parentheses. But what's even more useful is you can give those captures names, by using the `(?<name>pattern)` syntax. Like this:

```
(?<artist>[^\\]+)\\(?<album>[^\\]+)\\(?<track>\d+)[.]\s*(?<artist>[^\\]+)\s*-\s*(?<title>[^\\]+)[.]mp3$
```

And finally, how do you access the results?

```
Dim text As String = "G:\Music\G\Green Day\(2001) International Superhits!\02. Green Day - Poprocks & Coke.mp3" 
Dim pattern As String = "(?<artist>[^\\]+)\\(?<album>[^\\]+)\\(?<track>\d+)[.]\s*(?<artist>[^\\]+)\s*-\s*(?<title>[^\\]+)[.]mp3$" 

' Instantiate the regular expression object. 
Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern)

' Match the regular expression pattern against a text string. 
Dim m As Match = r.Match(text)
If m.Success Then
    ' get results from m.Groups["artist"].Value etc.
```

There is one more subtlety. Your mask/pattern contains the artist twice. .NET has no problem with a repeated group name. The question is how you want to handle the situation where they are two different names. The code as I've written it above will just give you the latter of the two versions. You can in fact access both of them in `m.Groups["artist"].Captures[0].Value` and `m.Groups["artist"].Captures[1].Value`.

If you want to assert that both of them are the same - and just not match if they are not the same - you can use a backreference in place of the second group. A backreference matches exactly what was captured by the group it references:

```
(?<artist>[^\\]+)\\(?<album>[^\\]+)\\(?<track>\d+)[.]\s*\k<artist>\s*-\s*(?<title>[^\\]+)[.]mp3$
```

The `\k<artist>` makes sure, that you match exactly the `artist` you found in the path.

Like pete, I can only recommend [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). To get further insight into the constructs I've used above, you might want to check out these subsections in particular:

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- [Grouping, Capturing and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Learning regex is definitely worth your time. Not only will you certainly come across another problem that is easily solved with them - it will also boost your productivity quite a lot when it comes to simple search-and-replace tasks in the text editor of your choice.

**EDIT:** One final note. If you are going to use this pattern a lot, and performance is critical, you might be able to gain a lot from using .NET's right-to-left mode. You can activate it like

```
...
Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
...
```

But if you want to know why that makes a difference, I suggest you read the linked tutorial. ;)

Comment: You sir are hereby declared a Regex ninja. Great explanation of what is happening and it worked the first time. Thank you so much.

Comment: Will do. This was my first question here. I surely appreciate it.

Comment: Have been testing this solution and it seems to work well except for the " - " part. I can remove the spaces and it will still match. If the mask is set to " - " I need the spaces to be there exactly as the mask shows. How do I change it to make sure each space is where it needs to be? I have been testing with Rubular expression tester and can't get it figured out. Thanks.

Comment: @RandyB. just change the *s (zero or more) to +s (one or more). or alternatively add two literal spaces around the hyphen

Comment: Hi. I had already tried that. I only need to allow 1 space if the mask only shows one space. I am building the regex with code so I need something I can "plug in" for each space that is present. Thanks again.

Comment: @RandyB. oh, right. Then you could just write one literal space and use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), to ensure that there are no further ones: `...\k<artist>(?<![ ])[ ]-[ ](?![ ])(?<title>[^\\]+)...`. Or you start replacing all the `[\\]+` by something more elaborate (like `[^\s\\]+(?:\s+[^\s\\]+)*`)  which ensures that each part consists of one or more non-space characters, separated by spaces (but not spaces surrounding it)... and then again you add in one literal space.

Comment: Ok, looked up lookarounds and think I understand them well enough. The negative lookaround seems to work for the space after the dash but not before the dash. Could it be because the artist name has a space in it or does it require a literal before it is used?

Comment: @RandyB, not sure without seeing your particular input. I think the other solution is more generic anyway when it comes to programmatically building the regex.

Comment: I'm going to start another question since this is a new problem and I can't figure it out. That way I can give the credit to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for you:

```
^(?<drive>[^:]+):\\(?<folder>Music)\\(?<subfolder>[^\\]+)\\(?<group>[^(]+)\\\((?<year>[^)]+)\)\s+(?<album>[^\\]+)\\(?<track>[^.]+)\.\s*(?<artist>.+?) - (?<title>[^.]+)\.mp3$
```

Breaking it down for an explanation:

```
^                       'start of string
(?<drive>[^:]+)         'named capture group "drive", captures any character except :
:\\                     'finds : followed by "\" ("\" has to be escaped to be a literal "\", so \\ is needed here)
(?<folder>Music)        'named capture group "folder", captures Music
\\                      'finds "\"
(?<subfolder>[^\\]+)    'named capture group "subfolder", captures any character except "\"
\\                      'finds "\"
(?<group>[^(]+)         'named capture group "group", captures any character except "\"
\\                      'finds "\"
\(                      'finds ( (parentheses must be escaped to be a literal "(" or literal ")", so \( is needed here)
(?<year>[^)]+)\)        'named capture group "year", captures any character except "("
\s+                     'finds whitespace
(?<album>[^\\]+)        'named capture group "album", captures any character except "("
\\                      'finds "\"
(?<track>[^.]+)         'named capture group "track", captures any character except "."
\.                      'finds "." (outside of a character class, "." must be escaped, so \. is needed here)
\s*                     'finds whitespace
(?<artist>.+?)          'named capture group "artist", captures any character (lazily)
 -                      'finds " - "
(?<title>[^.]+)         'named capture group "title", captures any character (greedily)
\.mp3                   'finds ".mp3"
$                       'end of string
```

This is a pretty good online primer for Regular Expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

I might add, for an offline resource, you could certainly do a lot worse than "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey E.F. Friedl from O'Reilly Media. I have the 2nd edition and it helped me understand Regex to the point where I rarely need to ask questions about Regex.

I also purchased (and love) RegexBuddy by Jan Goyvaerts. It's a phenomenal piece of software for composing and understanding Regex.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Yours worked too. Don't know if two people can answer a question but I'll click your check mark as well.